# Declare multiple worksheets as variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to declare some variables for the worksheets in this way

```
Dim e
For Each e In Array("Data", "CL", "SE", "GE", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "STP", "STF", "RH", "CR", "MC", "AW")
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(e)
Next e
```

Is it possible to declare all the worksheets using the 1d array ..? If not, is there a workaround to smart approach to do that ..?
example wsData to refer to the worksheet "Data"
and wsCL to refer to the worksheet "CL" and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Array of Worksheets

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetGroup()
    Dim wsArray As Variant, wsData As Variant, i As Long
    wsArray = Array("Data", "CL", "SE", "GE", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", _
      "E5", "STP", "STF", "RH", "CR", "MC", "AW")
    wsData = getWorksheets(wsArray)
    ' e.g.
    For i = 0 To UBound(wsData)
        Debug.Print wsData(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub

Function getWorksheets(wsArray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim wsData As Variant, ws As Variant, i As Long
    ReDim wsData(UBound(wsArray))
    For Each ws In wsArray
        Set wsData(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws)
        i = i + 1
    Next ws
    getWorksheets = wsData
End Function
```

**Helper Sub**

```
Sub AddSheets()
    Dim e As Variant
    For Each e In Array("Data", "CL", "SE", "GE", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", _
      "E5", "STP", "STF", "RH", "CR", "MC", "AW")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add , ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = e
    Next e
End Sub
```

### EDIT

**A Collection Version**

The main differences are that you have to use `Set`, you have to use `Add` so you don't need `i` and that the collection is **one-based**. Additionally there is the `Key` parameter which could possibly be exploited.

```
Sub WorksheetGroupColl()
    Dim wsArray, wsColl As Collection, i As Long
    wsArray = Array("Data", "CL", "SE", "GE", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", _
      "E5", "STP", "STF", "RH", "CR", "MC", "AW")
    Set wsColl = getWorksheetsColl(wsArray)
    ' e.g.
    For i = 1 To wsColl.Count
        Debug.Print wsColl(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub

Function getWorksheetsColl(wsArray As Variant) As Collection
    Dim wsColl As New Collection, ws As Variant
    For Each ws In wsArray
        wsColl.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws) ' There are more parameters.
    Next ws
    Set getWorksheetsColl = wsColl
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will study the code well as I think this is the most appropriate way to achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have variable variable names in VBA. What you can do though is refer to a worksheet by it's codename. For example:

```
with wsData
    'code
end with
```

Now Excel usually assigns codenames to the sheet in the form 'Sheet1", "Sheet2".. etc. What you'd want to do is to change those codenames to the name you want, so that you can refer to them as in your question. In order to change them you can run a loop like so:

```
Sub setSheetCodenames()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.[_CodeName] = "ws" & ws.Name
Next

End Sub
```

This will result in the sheet "Data" being able to be referred to as "wsData", sheet CL as "wsCL" and so forth.

Note: This assumes your sheets are already created. If they aren't then you need to create them first before running this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the built in [`Worksheets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets) collection like so...

```
For each e in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Now e represents a workbook object with each iteration
    Debug.Print e.Name
Next e
```

You could also use `Sheets` rather than `Worksheets`.

If desired you could use a `For...Next` loop too, like so...

```
For e = 1 to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(e).Name
Next e
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the target is declare variables for the those worksheets not just to loop through them .. In Brief, to declare several variables using loop.

Comment: @YasserKhalil  You can create an array of worksheets.  But how does your code know `Wshts(5)` is `Worksheets("E1")`?  Please tell us more about what you are trying to achieve so we can advise you.

Comment: I am working on a large project and I need an easier way to declare using the worksheets .. so t thought of declaring public variables for the worksheets ..